# Running Macro's after losing focus

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm trying to copy a Range from Excel into Word and paste it as an image.

My setup currently is:

- WORD runs a Macro, which creates an Excel object and opens Workbook1.xlsm
- WORD calls a macro on Workbook1.xlsm
- The macro copies a range onto the clipboard.
- WORD then pastes the clipboard as an image.

After the pasting in WORD, I can no longer call any macro's in the referenced Excel document. My code, which lives in a WORD VBA macro:

```
Dim xl As Object
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Workbooks.Open ("\\path\to\DESKTOP\qrap\xlsHelper.xlsm")

For i = 0 To 10
    xl.Run "copy", "\\path\to\DESKTOP\qrap\pieces\2003 2015-2 finance.xls"

    Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, _
        Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
Next

xl.ActiveWorkbook.Close (False)
xl.Quit
Set xl = Nothing
```

On the second iteration, the line `xl.Run ...` throws a `Runtime Error 1004: Macro cannot be executed`. Runs fine the first time. Runs fine if I don't switch to WORD.

How can I refocus to Excel, so that the macro can run properly?

Additionally, the `copy` macro in the Excel file is this:

```
Dim oWb As Workbook

Public Sub copy(filename As String)
    If Not (oWb Is Nothing) Then
        oWb.Close
        Set oWb = Nothing
    End If

    Set oWb = Workbooks.Open(filename)
    ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.copy
End Sub
```

Comment: What does the `copy` code look like?

Comment: @Rory added the code for the Excel Macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are being left with a workbook open. Make sure there aren't any Excel instances running in the background, then change your code to:

```
Dim xl                        As Object
Dim wb                        As Object
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Workbooks.Open "\\path\to\DESKTOP\qrap\xlsHelper.xlsm"

For i = 0 To 10
    xl.Run "xlsHelper.xlsm!copy", "\\path\to\DESKTOP\qrap\stukken\2003 2015-2 financieel.xls"

    Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, _
                           Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
Next

xl.Activeworkbook.Close False
xl.Quit
```

and try that.

Comment: This gives the exact same result; closing the workbooks is not the problem. In fact, I need this one to stay open and open other workbooks for me. Further, if that was the problem, the excel-macro would throw an error, not the WORD one.

Comment: I've made one amendment to the code - can you retest?

Comment: That's it! Works like a charm! - I can now see the logic behind my error, and gaining insights on these things is always way better than copy/pasting code. thnx